# Resistor value of R1 and R2

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, thevenin

[image]

i came across a problem in circuit analysis ,i have given a circuit and it's thevenin equivalent circuit
**Given Parameters** are **R3(load resistor)=10k**, **Rth=40.2k,Vth=5v** and in the circuit diagram on left **source Voltage V1=12v**,the voltage across R3 is also given i.e **Vl=1v**
**to find** value of resistor R1 and R2 , i know the **Rth=R1 || R2** and **Vth=V1(R2/R1+R2)** but how can i relate this two equations to find value of **R1** and **R2**

Comment: `Rth` and `Vth` are known to you. So you have two equations with two unknowns `R1` and `R2`. Solve?

Comment: R1 is 40% greater than R2 by simple visual inspection.

Comment: @AJN i solved using this method but i am getting resistor value in mOhms

Comment: \$R_{th}/R_1 = R_2/(R1+R2)\$. Substitute this in the second equation to get \$V_{th}\cdot R1 = V\cdot R_{th}\$. Find R1 from this.

Comment: i got R2=68.91K and R1=96.4K, i also re-checked by calculating the Rth and Vth thanks for help@AJN